# php request/post/get/session expiration

Tags: php, session, post, get, request

I know a SESSION can expire but what about $_REQUEST/$_POST/$_GET variables?

My question is, I have users that submit information and I need to set a Id for that  information before I insert it into a database. Now I thought about using a SESSION but the problem is if the session expires before the user has submitted the information to the database they loose the Id I need. Would passing it the $_REQUEST/$_POST/$_GET variable(s) be a better solution or should I just use a variable and readjust the script?

Also I was using SESSION as it's very easy to call from inside a function without passing it in.

```
function setInfo() {
   // no need to pass I can call from within
   $Id = $_SESSION['Id'];
}
```

Is this good practice?

EDIT:
Would this be better as a cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first question would be, are you not able to insert a row and retrieve a auto-incrementing ID with @@IDENTITY?. you can't really "Store" data in $_REQUEST, $_POST or $_GET, that data is only there from when the client submits a page, form, link request to the server to when you finish and send to output the resulting page. Either way, you would most likely use the $_SESSION space to store the info that needs to be carried to other pages.

Comment: This is what I'm doing now but running into the problem of users session expiring. That causes the id to be reset and a new id is issued. I was using SESSION to hold the pre-fetched database record Id as the id

Comment: understandable about the $_REQUEST, $_POST or $_GET just looking for another method to store the information if without regenerating the Id on session experation. good tips though thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden field in the form, and store the the *value* of hidden field in database ("maybe or very probably" you will need a separate table for this). When user submits the form you check that the submitted *value* for hidden var exists in the database.

When the request from particular *value* is processed, delete it from database.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that as a basis of security. Even if the field is hidden, I can still manipulate it on the client side. it would help in keeping the data there for the life of the form, but it wouldn't amount to security.